# Which design patterns are useful to do this?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, device-manager

I have a device which have low level programming. I am giving version numbers every new devices and upgrades. I also have a program which communicate with these devices (to retrieving information on these devices).

For eg. `v1.2` sends this kind of string:

```
v1.2|Time|Conductivity|Repetation|Time|Heat of First Nozzle|Pressure|EndOfMessage
```

but new version of device program:

```
v1.3|Time|Conductivity|Repetation|Time|Humadity|1st Nozzle Heat;2nd Nozzle Heat|Pressure|EndOfMessage
```

My test application will retrieve **information** and change the **operation** of this device. **Some operations will have in `v1.2` device some not.** I thought strategy design pattern seems useful for this situation but I'm not sure. Which design pattern should I use to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this would be a good use-case for the Stategy pattern, although you will also use the Factory pattern to create a specific parser instance.

Your code should then generally look something like this:

```
public DeviceInfo Parse(InputData input)
{
    var version = versionParser.Parse(input);
    var concreteParser = parserFactory.CreateFor(version);
    var data = concreteParser.Parse(data);
    return data;
}
```

For a simple project with few parsers, you may hardcode your parser factory:

```
public class ParserFactory
{
    public static IParser<DeviceInfo> CreateFor(Version version)
    {
        // instantiate proper parser based on version
    }
}
```

Depending on the size of your project, you may also decide to use a plugin pattern for your parsers ([System.AddIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145020.aspx) contains useful classes for managing plugins).

Comment: That is a great answer. I would also point out at the less technical http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 0):

I feel Strategy along with Factory method will solve the purpose.